# GitHub Desktop не видит разные участки кода при слияние веток

Tags: git, github

На гит хабе есть 2 ветки
хочу сделать слияние, но гитхаб desktop пишет что ветки уже одинаковы, хотя на самом сайте в файлах разные строки кода

Comment: А вы синхронизацию делали?

Comment: Вы имете ввиду pull? Просто недавно начал изучение, и столкнулся с такой проблемой

Comment: И pull и push. И вообще покажите git branch -a